# PHP errors not being shown when using error_reporting and ini_set (PHP module in Apache 2.2)

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

I am trying to use error_reporting() in order to show all errors in my php script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

However, while php errors are properly logged, none of the functions above show the errors in the page.

I know the error reporting can be properly set in the php.ini file (I know how to that), but I don't understand why it can't be changed on the fly using the standard php functions.

I am suspecting Apache not authorizing to do so (php is installed as a module, config file is in  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini )

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: I already mentioned error_reporting(E_ALL) in the question.

Comment: I know but you have to set display errors to on, i.e. ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: I'm so sorry, you are right, problem fixed, many thanks for your help.